# Почему не задается значение None в sqlite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite3

Пытаюсь задать значение None в колонку с название USERNAME через команду UPDATE

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET USERNAME = {None} WHERE ID = {1829785381}")
```

Нужно задать именно занчение `NoneType`, не строку со значением `'None'`, выдает ошибку
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: None`
Подскажите может не правильно оформляю команду вплане синтаксиса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при ручном составлении строки запроса, вы ее и получите, проверьте, у вас должен получить такой запрос:

```sql
UPDATE users SET USERNAME = None WHERE ID = 1829785381
```

А `None` в текущем контексте будет выглядеть как столбец этой же таблице

Вместо ручного формирования, лучше используйте биндинги:

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET USERNAME = ? WHERE ID = ?", (None, 1829785381))
```

---

**P.S.**

Вообще, в SQL вместо питоничьего `None` используется `null`, драйвер базы данных сам это сконвертирует, если использовать биндинги, но вы можете это сделать и сами, указав `null` в запросе:

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET USERNAME = null WHERE ID = {1829785381}")
```

Или:

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET USERNAME = null WHERE ID = ?", (1829785381,))
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: @Avgxst, пожалуйста :)